# How to update MPNowPlayingInfoCenter when in the background and the track in AVQueuePlayer changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

So I am trying to update MPNowPlayingInfoCenter when in the background and the track in AVQueuePlayer changes.

In the foreground it is easy in

```
- (id) init{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinish) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];

  player = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc]init];
  player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndPause;
}

-(void)didFinish{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
  // Magic goes here
  //[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:nowPlaying]; 
  [player advanceToNextItem];
  [player play];
}
```

In the background however without AVPlayerActionAtItemEndAdvance it does not go to the next one and AVPlayerActionAtItemEndAdvance never calls didFinish in the background

```
- (id) init{
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(didFinish) name:AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification object:nil];

  player = [[AVQueuePlayer alloc]init];
  player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndAdvance;
}

-(void)didFinish{ //never called
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
  // Magic goes here
  //[[MPNowPlayingInfoCenter defaultCenter] setNowPlayingInfo:nowPlaying]; 
  //play is not needed in this case
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use KVO:

```
[self.queuePlayer addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"currentItem" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:PlayerItemKVOContext];
```

and

```
- (void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {

    if (context == PlayerItemKVOContext) {
        AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [_queuePlayer currentItem];
```

Comment: Does not work! Well it does when the app is in the foreground but when the lockscreen activated for example the picture/text does not change when the track does.

Comment: and you have audio background mode enabled?

Comment: Yes thanks it worked it just took me a while to figure out.

Comment: All my code, full working example is here if anyone need to have a look (bit messy but works) https://github.com/etiennea/phonegap-plugin-mediaplayer